# Returning the smallest value within an Array List

Tags: arraylist

I need to write a method that returns me the smallest distance (which is a whole number value) within an Array List called "babyTurtles". There are 5 turtles within this array list and they all move a random distance each time the program is ran.

I've been trying to figure out how to do it for an hour and all I've accomplished is making myself frustrated and coming here.

p.s.
In my class we wrote this code to find the average distance moved by the baby turtles:

```
public double getAverageDistanceMovedByChildren() {
    if (this.babyTurtles.size() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    double sum = 0;

    for (Turtle currentTurtle : this.babyTurtles) {
        sum = sum + currentTurtle.getDistanceMoved();
    }

    double average = sum / this.babyTurtles.size();
    return average;

}
```

That's all I've got to work on, but I just can't seem to find out how to do it.
I'd really appreciate it if you could assist me.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the index in the array list of the smallest number:

```java
int lowestIndex = distanceList.indexOf(Collections.min(distanceList));
```

You can then get the value using this:

```java
int lowestDistance = distanceList.get(lowestIndex);
```

Comment: Can you show me how to do it using a loop? That's what I need.

Comment: You have a great example of a loop in the code that you posted. In fact, the code to find the minimum will be almost identical, just a little simpler.